# How to identify an image read in Google Docs?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a document with text and images and I would like to create a GAS that would read my document and identifies what kind of element it read.  My script goes ...

```
function myFunction() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById('doc_ID');
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var paragraphs = body.getParagraphs();
  var images = doc.getBody().getImages();

  Logger.log("There are " + images.length + " images found");
  Logger.log("There are " + paragraphs.length + " paragraph found");

  paragraphs.forEach(function (data, index) {
      Logger.log(index+1 + ' is ' + data.getType()); //returns an ElementType
  });
}
```

with the result of

[image: screen shot]

It is shown that it found 2 images placed on number 2 and 7 where the images are.

```
var images = doc.getBody().getImages();  //returned 2 InlineImage
```

but why does data.getType() displays everything as PARAGRAPH if there were two INLINE_IMAGE?  Is there another way to identify it read an image instead of text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some elements in each paragraph. So when you want to retrieve `INLINE_IMAGE`, how about this modification?

#### From :

```
paragraphs.forEach(function (data, index) {
  Logger.log(index+1 + ' is ' + data.getType()); //returns an ElementType
});
```

#### To :

```
paragraphs.forEach(function (data, index) {
  Logger.log(index+1 + ' is ' + data.getType()); //returns an ElementType
  for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumChildren(); i++) { // Added
    Logger.log(data.getChild(i).getType()); // Added
  }
});
```

#### References :

- [getChild(childIndex)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#getChild(Integer))

If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thank you for the info I am new in this community so I kinda forget the things I am supposed to do.  Again thank you.

Comment: @Pepay No problem. Thank you, too.